# Cakephp email gives error : "Connection timed out"

Tags: email, cakephp

I am sending email with CakePHP framework.
Following is the code I have added in function :

```
App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
$Email = new CakeEmail('gmail');
$Email->from(array(
    ADMIN_EMAIL => 'kioui'
));
$Email->to('pankhiwalia@gmail.com');
$Email->subject('test');
$Email->emailFormat('text');
$p = $Email->send();
```

and under `Config/email.php` file I have added following smtp settings:

```
public $smtp = array( 
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array(ADMIN_EMAIL => ADMIN_NAME),
        'host' => 'ssl://localhost',
        'username' => 'kiouiapp@kioui-apps.com',
        'password' => 'Fr00Fr00',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        'timeout' => '30',
        'tls' => false,
        'port' => 465,           
);
```

Please tell me did I miss any line?

Comment: There is a comma missing after the `'username' => '************'`. Is that a typo or what is in your email.php?

Comment: username is kiouiapp@kioui-apps.com

Comment: did u try by increasing the timeout ?

Comment: yes  i have tried.. ihave even tried by commenting the timeout line